# Is there any possibility of showing the fragment UI in the screen while getActivity() returning null in a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm creating an android application that contains one main activity and three fragments. There is a side navigation bar and depend on the selected menu item, it will replace the fragment loaded into the main screen.

In one of those fragments, I'm loading data from a REST API and once the data received, it will update the fragment UI. I'm using `ok-http` to send REST API calls. So in the `onResponse()` method, I have to call `getActivity().runOnUiThread()` to update the UI elements with received data and show Toast notifications for errors.

I already read that there is a chance to return `null` while calling `getActivity()` method within a fragment due to detach the fragment from the activity. I'm also aware that it's not a good idea to create a reference to the activity in `onAttach()` method and use it later like below, since it will prevent GC to clean that activity object after detaching from the fragment.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    mActivity = (Activity)context;
}
```

Therefore I'm currently doing null check before calling `getActivity()` method as shown below which is recommended in most of the SO answers.

```
if (getActivity() != null) {
   getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> {
         //Update UI
     }
   );
}
```

But according to the above code block, It's obvious that if there is no activity attached to the fragment (when `getActivity()` returns `null`), the UI will not be updated.

It's okay to not executing the UI updates if the fragment is not on the screen anymore. So my question is, is there any possibility of showing the fragment UI to the user while `getActivity()` returning `null`?